# Convert bytes to UInt16 in Swift 4

Tags: swift, bluetooth, byte

I'm trying to get values from an object bluetooth. This object has GATT Characteristics and I receive bytes which I want to convert to Int or Float because this values are only understandable in this format like temperature, pressure, ...

I use this method :

```
let value = UnsafePointer(bytes).withMemoryRebound(to: UInt16.self, capacity: 1) {
        $0.pointee
    }
```

The variable bytes is an array of 2 UInt8. It's working great only when values are positives because

I'm trying to get some values of the accelerometer of my bluetooth object (values are on 3 axis X, Y and Z).

The value of axis X should be around -0.3 and I'm getting a big positive value like 655.

Do you have an idea on what's going on ?

Comment: Why are you expecting a value of around -0.3 if you're interpreting the bytes as a `UInt16`? It'll be a positive integer. Although note that `UnsafePointer(bytes).withMemoryRebound(to: UInt16.self, capacity: 1)` is *undefined behaviour* (assuming `bytes` is as you say a `[UInt8]`) – the pointer from `bytes` is only guaranteed to be valid for the duration of the `UnsafePointer` initialiser call (I really wish there'd be a warning for that).

Comment: Apart from that, you're assuming the elements in `bytes` are in the same order as your host's endianness (almost certainly LE, so least significant byte first, most significant byte last) – and I'm guessing that probably isn't the case here. But anyway, please post a [mcve] :)

Comment: You're right, I cast to Int16 instead of UInt16 and It's working great. Thank you